# Computing empirical Beta in a given distribution [SOLVED]

Tags: r, statistics, beta

I have to [calculate an empirical β](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#Table_of_error_types) and compare it with the theoretical one by measuring the difference. This is the model to develop the new code:

```
if (!require("pwr")) install.packages("pwr")

# parameters
N=1000
n = 25
k = 500
a_teo = 0.05

#Here we create the universe 
poblacion <- rnorm(N, 10, 10)
m.pob <- mean(poblacion)
sd.pob <- sd(poblacion)

#Data simulation and store of p.values
p <- vector(length=k)
for (i in 1:k){
 muestra <- poblacion[sample(1:N, n)]
 p[i] <- t.test(muestra, mu=15)$p.value
}

#Empiric beta
beta_emp <- length(p[p>a_teo])/k

#Theoretical beta
d=(10 - 15) / sd.pob
beta_teo <- 1 - pwr.t.test(n,
                           d=d,
                           sig.level=a_teo,
                            type="one.sample")$power
#Print theoretical vs empirical bet
sprintf("beta_teo = %.3f -- beta_emp = %.3f -- Diff = %.3f", beta_teo, beta_emp, beta_teo-beta_emp)
```

Using the previous as reference, I have to run a simulation of a distribution that's NOT 'normal', but instead just have values in the range (2, 3, 4, 5) and measure the difference between Empirical and Theoretical beta. This is my code:

```
if (!require("pwr")) install.packages("pwr")

N=1000
n = 25
k = 500
a_teo = .05

poblacion <- sample(2:5, N, replace = T)
m.pob <- mean(poblacion)
sd.pob <- sd(poblacion)

p <- vector(length=k)
for (i in seq_along(p)){
  muestra <- sample(2:5, N, replace = T)
  p[i] <- t.test(muestra, mu=m.pob)$p.value
}

#Empiric beta
beta_emp <- length(p[p>a_teo])/k

#Theoretical beta
d=(10 - m.pob) / sd.pob
beta_teo <- 1 - pwr.t.test(n,
                           d=d,
                           sig.level=a_teo,
                           type="one.sample")$power
sprintf("beta_teo = %.3f -- beta_emp = %.3f -- Diff = %.3f", beta_teo, beta_emp, beta_teo-beta_emp)
```

I get 'zero' as the value for the theoretical beta. Can someone tell me where is the problem? The '10' value is the mean from the example, so it should probably be changed for this one.

Comment: Other potential issues aside, please note that in your code `poblacion` is an n = 1000 sample of the numbers 2 to 5, while `muestra` is an n = 1000 sample of the 2nd to 5th item of `poblacion` - which is probably not what you intended?

Comment: Absolutely, @I_O, I just edited. What are those potential issues aside?

Comment: Another issue is the loop you intend to fill the vector of probabilities `p` with. In your loop construct, `i` returns `FALSE` each iteration (inspect p). Use `for (i in seq_along(p))` instead, or more idiomatic: `p <- replicate(k, t.test(sample(2:5, N, replace = T),  mu = m.pob)$p.value)`.

Comment: Thanks, @I_O. Your comments have improved my code, there is something wrong - I always get '0.000' as theoretical value.

Comment: So do I, but I don't really grasp the concept behind the code ;-) e. g.: whence the difference `(10-15)` used for parameter `d` in the power test. That, however, is a question of *statistics* rather than their *implementation with R*, so https://stats.stackexchange.com/ would be the appropriate forum.

Comment: The difference is the mean from the normally distributed sample ('10') and 15 is the mean (mu = 15 inside for loop). That's for a normal, I don't know how to apply it to a non-normally distribution.

Comment: I've asked in stats.stackexchange.com about it and they consider it to be a programming/debugging issue, so more appropriate for this website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257126/discussion-between-i-o-and-behsci).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several misunderstood points.

- you have to simulate a Gaussian (=normal) sample with `rnorm`, but you use `sample`
- the effect size is `(mu - mu1) / sd`, where `mu` is the actual population mean of your simulated samples and `mu1` is the population mean under the alternative hypothesis

```r
library(pwr)

n = 20   # sample size
k = 5000 # number of simulated samples
a_teo = .05

m.pob <- 2 # population mean under H1
mu <- 1    # actual population mean
stdev <- 1.5

p <- numeric(k)
for (i in seq_along(p)){
  muestra <- rnorm(n, mu, stdev)
  p[i] <- t.test(muestra, mu = m.pob)$p.value
}

#Empiric beta
beta_emp <- length(p[p>a_teo])/k

#Theoretical beta
d <- (mu - m.pob) / stdev
beta_teo <- 1 - pwr.t.test(n,
                           d = d,
                           sig.level = a_teo,
                           type = "one.sample")$power
sprintf("beta_teo = %.3f -- beta_emp = %.3f -- Diff = %.3f", beta_teo, beta_emp, beta_teo-beta_emp)
```